# XSLT 2.0 Get distinct values using multiple elements

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have child element "Report_Entry" with sibling elements "employeeID, plan and startDate".
I want to find distinct values using the sibling elements.
If the combination of three elements is repeating, I want to eliminate any duplicate values.

I am not sure how to use distinct values based on multiple elements. I started going down the path of group-by by joining the strings and then split it once I get the group by value, but lost my way.
group-by="string-join((employeeID,plan,startDate), '|')">

The XML data

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Report_Data>
   <Report_Entry>
      <employeeID>0123</employeeID>
      <plan>plan1</plan>
      <startDate>2021-01-31</startDate>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <employeeID>0123</employeeID>
      <plan>plan1</plan>
      <startDate>2021-01-31</startDate>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <employeeID>0123</employeeID>
      <plan>plan2</plan>
      <startDate>2021-02-15</startDate>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <employeeID>0124</employeeID>
      <plan>plan1</plan>
      <startDate>2021-01-31</startDate>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <employeeID>0124</employeeID>
      <plan>plan2</plan>
      <startDate>2021-01-31</startDate>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <employeeID>0125</employeeID>
      <plan>plan1</plan>
      <startDate>2021-01-31</startDate>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <employeeID>0125</employeeID>
      <plan>plan1</plan>
      <startDate>2021-04-22</startDate>
   </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

The output I am expecting. From the above output, employeeID 0123 with plan1 and startdat 0221-01-31 is repeating which I want to eliminate.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Report_Data>
   <Report_Entry>
      <employeeID>0123</employeeID>
      <plan>plan1</plan>
      <startDate>2021-01-31</startDate>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <employeeID>0123</employeeID>
      <plan>plan2</plan>
      <startDate>2021-02-15</startDate>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <employeeID>0124</employeeID>
      <plan>plan1</plan>
      <startDate>2021-01-31</startDate>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <employeeID>0125</employeeID>
      <plan>plan1</plan>
      <startDate>2021-01-31</startDate>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <employeeID>0125</employeeID>
      <plan>plan1</plan>
      <startDate>2021-04-22</startDate>
   </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

Comment: Please post the XSL you've tried.

Comment: JSmart523 - 
I first started a different approach. I grouped the data by using " group-by="string-join((employeeID,plan,startDate), '|')">" and hoped to try and split it using another XSLT and I lost my way. I tried few examples which are available online to get distinct which did not suit my example.

Comment: Please show us your attempt and how it failed or first look at the relevant examples in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info. You seem to have the right grouping key and usually, if all you want is eliminate the duplicates, inside of `for-each-group` you only need to process the first item in the group which conveniently is the context item `.` so doing `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>` will process only the first item of the group.